# Check status of previous MySQL query and execute next query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, pdo

I want to execute multiple MySQL queries. Where the next query depends on the status of the previous one. I need to check the `status of the query` and in some cases also `rowCount()`. If the first query returns what I want the next query will be executed and so on. If one of them fail the whole process will be stopped.

I usually `nest my queries inside of a try/catch block`. Is there a better way to do this? Here is my code. I do not want you to fix my code just see it and give me any suggestions. I'm using `PDO` with `MySQL 5.6.26`.

Thanks

```
$updated = false;
//#1
$query = "select username, forgot_code, time, valid from forgot_requests where forgot_code = :forgot_code";

try {
    $run_query = $db->prepare($query);
    $run_query->execute(array(':forgot_code' => $_POST['forgot_code']));
    $data = $run_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    //13min = 780s
    if($run_query->rowCount() == 1 && (time() - $data->time < 7800000) && $data->valid) {

        //#2
        $query = "update users set password = :password where username = :username";

        try {
            $run_query = $db->prepare($query);
            $run_query->execute(array(
                ':password' => password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
                ':username' => $data->username
            ));

            //#3
            $query = "update forgot_requests set valid = 0 where forgot_code = :forgot_code";

            try {
                $run_query = $db->prepare($query);
                $run_query->execute(array(':forgot_code' => $_POST['forgot_code']));

                //update
                $updated = true;

            } catch(PDOException $e) {}

        } catch(PDOException $e) {}

    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {}
```

Comment: Do you have an issue with this code, or are you just asking for feedback on if it is a good method?

Comment: I do not have any issues with the code but I think it is not a good practice .  @Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to enforce a valid database state with your pre cautions.

MySQL and PDO offer you the concept of transactions to ensure that a series of sql statements will only be executed all together.

Example

```
<?php
$db->beginTransaction();

// Query 2
$query = "update users set password = :password where username = :username";
$run_query = $db->prepare($query);
$run_query->execute(array(
  ':password' => password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
  ':username' => $data->username
 ));

// Query 3
$query = "update forgot_requests set valid = 0 where forgot_code = :forgot_code";
$run_query = $db->prepare($query);
$run_query->execute(array(':forgot_code' => $_POST['forgot_code']));

// All queries will be executed or no query will be executed
$db->commit();
?>
```

If you encounter any problems you can roll back a transaction:

```
<?php
$db->rollBack();
?>
```

Further information can be found in MySql manual: (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html) and in php documentation (http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.begintransaction.php)